# Accessing ajax POST response in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm making ajax POST request from javascript function:

```
function UpdateMetrics() {
   $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "MyHandler.ashx?Param1=value1",
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "text",
              success: function (msg) {
                  var jsonUpdatedData = msg;
                  ...
              }
          });
}
```

From my handler, I'm sending json string with:

```
context.Response.write(json);
```

I think I'll get it in `msg`.

I also want to send other string (count). So I'm trying to use header info along with json data. So I added this line:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("MaxCount",Convert.ToString(tempList.Count));
```

If this is right way to do it, how can I access it in my `success` function?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest returning data in the response header.  If you must return a count param, why not append it to your json?  Or, if your json is returning an array of data, why not just get the array.length in javascript?

Comment: You can just send it like, newdata={'data':json,'count':count}, send newdata instead of json. Sending via header is not recommended.

Comment: Actually `count` is some different count. It is not related with json string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access headers in your `success` function, add in 2 more arguments to your function, the status code and the jqXHR object, which you can read the documentation for at [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

So, your function should look like:

```
success: function (msg, status, jqXHR) {
    var jsonUpdatedData = msg;
    ...
}
```

However, as pointed out in comments, it's probably best not to use the header to send data. You should probably just include it in the json you send out.

You also need to tell jQuery to interpret the response as json by setting

```
dataType: "json"
```

Otherwise, it will just be returned to you as text.

Comment: Setting `dataType` isn't necessary if the response from the server has a valid Content-type. jQuery will use this to attempt to convert the response's value to the type specified. It isn't always just text

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to get the header data in ajax post success can be achieved using getResponseHeader method please refer the below code snippet.

```
function UpdateMetrics() {
var callback =  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "MyHandler.ashx?Param1=value1",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "text",
          success: function (msg) {

          var jsonUpdatedData = msg;
        var headerdata = callback.getResponseHeader("MaxCount"); 
// Where MaxCount is name provided in the header.
   ...
          }
      });
}
```

Thanks